# Aerospike PHP Session Serializer igbinary

Tags: php, session, serialization, aerospike

Using Aerospike as a backend for PHP sessions, I would like to change default serializer from "php" to "igbinary".

Here is my stack :

- Linux Debian Jessie 8.4
- PHP 5.6.20
- Aerospike Community Server v3.8.2.3
- PHP client library v3.4.8
- igbinary v1.2.1

Here is a simple sample PHP script for testing:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('session.save_handler','aerospike');
ini_set('session.save_path','sessions|sess|127.0.0.1:3000');

// Start session
session_start();

// Write session
$_SESSION['test'] = time();

// Read session
$db = new Aerospike(["hosts" => [[ "addr" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 3000 ]]]);
$key = $db->initKey('sessions', 'sess', session_id());
$status = $db->get($key, $record);

echo htmlentities($record['bins']['PHP_SESSION']);
```

This works as expected. Here the output:

```
test|i:1464615088;
```

If I change session serializer with **wddx** for example, it still works:

```
<?php

[...]

ini_set('session.save_handler','aerospike');
ini_set('session.save_path','sessions|sess|127.0.0.1:3000');
ini_set('session.serialize_handler', 'wddx');

[...]
```

Here is the output:

```
<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><struct><var name='test'><number>1464615227</number></var></struct></data></wddxPacket>
```

But when I change serializer with **igbinary**, like this:

```
<?php

[...]

ini_set('session.save_handler','aerospike');
ini_set('session.save_path','sessions|sess|127.0.0.1:3000');
ini_set('session.serialize_handler', 'igbinary');
```

session value is not saved (no row found in aerospike). Here is the output:

```
Notice: Undefined index: bins in /var/www/test.php on line 42
```

Notice that igbinary seems to work well with the default PHP session backend (files)

```
#ini_set('session.save_handler','aerospike');
#ini_set('session.save_path','sessions|sess|127.0.0.1:3000');
ini_set('session.serialize_handler', 'igbinary');

[...]

echo $_SESSION['test'];
$_SESSION['test'] = time();
```

This outputs "1464615840" or so (after refresh), as expected.

**Am I missing some configuration option in order to use igbinary as a serializer for Aerospike sessions?**

**Does anyone has already used igbinary as a serializer for Aerospike with success?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open [pull request](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-php/pull/103) that fixes it, likely to roll out with the upcoming PHP7 compatible release.